# In App Purchase for updates?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, auto-update

I need some advice on which path to go down to add some self-update capability to my app.

I've got an app in the App Store that uses a database full of information that needs to be updated periodically. Up until now I have been updating the db only when I push a new version through the store. We need the ability to update the db quicker. I'm getting ready to build in a feature that will allow the application to get an updated db when needed.

My question, can or should the Store Kit framework be used for this sort of thing? I was going to build it myself but would rather not reinvent the wheel. Any ideas what Apple's view on this is? The db delivers no new functionality just updates to keep the dataset current.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, this can be done via in-app purchase. Apple has said that no executable code can be downloaded, so the only real options are unlocking previously 'hidden' features, and grabbing new or updated data. You can do either a single-time upgrade (ie, pay $1.99 to get updated data for the life of the app), or a multi-time option (pay $1.99 to get update A, and then another $1.99 to get update B). You may want to do this as a subscription, but keep in mind that subscriptions are not automatic, and the user has to manually re-authorize each time their account is billed.

Comment: Also, there is no free in store app purchase product in case you wanted it to be free. $0.99 minimum.